# But what a [something]!

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, american-english, british-english

Is “but what a…” a correct way to emphasize on something, that was great? This phrase is sort of taken out from my native language and I wonder if it works the same in US/UK english.

Example:
“It was only one day.”
“But what a day!”

Meaning that even though it was only one day, it was amazing.

Comment: It's not *always* "positive". For example, *Our flight wasn't cancelled. It was only a delay - but **what** a delay!*

Comment: This usage (using ***what a*** as an "intensifier") looks *slightly* different to the definition you'll most easily find relating to *expressing an opinion*, as in expressions of sympathy such as ***What a shame!, What a pity he can't come!***, etc. But imho they're essentially the same.